# Working with enums in Scala

Tags: java, scala

I have Scala-style enum

```
object SomeObject {

  final object SomeEnum extends Enumeration {
    type SomeEnum = Value
    val val1, val2, val3 = Value
  }
```

How do I:

1) Call `valueOf` method to be able to get the value by its string representation?

```
val possibleVal3 = SomeObject.SomeEnum.valueOf("val3")
```

2) Call Java's analog of ordinal:

```
val a = SomeObject.SomeEnum.val2
a.ordinal
```

There are no such methods in `SomeEnum`, obviously.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. `withName()`:

   ```
   val possibleVal3 = SomeObject.SomeEnum.withName("val3")
   ```
2. `id`:

   ```
   val ordinal = SomeObject.SomeEnum.val2.id
   ```

**See also:**

- [`Enumeration`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.Enumeration)

Comment: What actually happens at this line: val Mon, Tue, Wed, Thu, Fri, Sat, Sun = Value? I can see that "Enumeration.Value" is an abstract class so how does it work?

Comment: `Value` in this line is not a type name, it's a `protected` method that creates new values.

Comment: The up-votes on this Q&A must say something deep about API design and Enumeration.